# How to call a pushNotification only when the application is in sleep mode from portable project

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using a `CrossPlateForm` technique to Create Android and IOS app using xamarine, i want to send push notification when my application is in sleep mode,
this is my method

```
 public void pushNotifications(int count)
    {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
           .SetContentTitle("new Messages")
            .SetContentText("Hello World! This is my first notification!")
           .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

        // Instantiate the Inbox style:
        Notification.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new Notification.InboxStyle();

        // Set the title and text of the notification:
        builder.SetContentTitle(count+" new messages");
        //builder.SetContentText("chimchim@xamarin.com");


        // Plug this style into the builder:
        builder.SetStyle(inboxStyle);

        // Build the notification:
        Notification notification = builder.Build();

        // Get the notification manager:
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        // Publish the notification:
        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);

    }
```

the count will come from a service which i wrote in portable project, when i tried to write `pushNotification` method in portable project `Notification.Builder` i cannot access `Notification` namespace. I want to trigger a method in `portable` project whenever applications to sleepmode and show the count using `pushNotification`, or is their any alternative way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "sleep mode"? Is [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95625/what-is-androids-sleep-mode)?

Answer (score 0):

You should try call your method on App.cs inside the OnSleep function:

```
public class App : Application  
{
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
        // Your method here
    }
```

Comment: but before that i need to call my service to get the count of messages and then i should call notificatin method, then how to call my service from here?

Comment: Did you have some kind of sync service class in your code @SyedRasheed?

Comment: yes i have sync service to get count, when its onsleep i should call that and show that count in notification and that sync service is in portable project of solution.